# Qt - QUdpSocket bind failed constantly

Tags: c++, qt, udp, qudpsocket, qhostaddress

I have these 2 lines of code. 
I need a socket that just receives data

The first method is working, and I receive date (from the ip/port in the second method)

The second method is always returning false.

I don't understand the difference and can't find the problem.

Any one have any idea how to resolve this or what I'm doing wrong?

```
 udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(); 
bool result = udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 7755);


QHostAddress address("the ip") 
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(); 
bool result = udpSocket->bind(address , 7755);
```

Answer (score 2):

In first method, when you bind the socket `bind(QHostAddress::Any, 7755)` it will listen on all   interfaces on your system; thus it will bind successfully knowing that at least one interface is up.

In the second method, when you set the IP Address with `QHostAddress address("the ip")` you need to make sure that an interface is up with that IP address at your system (use `ipconfig` on Win / `ifconfig` on Linux).
Now the constructor will automatically detect from the string passed ("ip address") whether its IPv4 or IPv6.
If you are not specifying a type, then you can construct the address as `Any` and bind your socket to it:

```
QString string("192.168.1.1");
QHostAddress address(QHostAddress::Any);
address.setAddress(string);
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket();
bool result = udpSocket->bind(address , 7755);
```